# Finding the radius of convergence, and explicit expression, for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{2n}$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

> I was given the function $$f\left(x\right)\ =\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}\cdot x^{2n}}{2n}$$ and asked to find the radius of convergence and an explicit expression of $f$ without the sigma.

I've found that the radious is $\left|x\right|\le1$ that that the function is awfuly similar to that of
$$\arctan x = \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ but for the life of me I can't figure out what to do with the 2n+1 in the denominator to turn it into something that resembles my function.. I've spent like 2 hour trying to figure out what to do and I have no direction..

Comment: Hint: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} x^{2n} }}{{2n}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{n}(x^2 )^n } 
$$

Answer (score 2):

By properties of power series we can differentiate $f$ to get $f'(x)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (-1)^{n+1} x^{2n-1}$. We can write this as $f'(x)=-\frac 1  x \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (-x^{2})^{n}$. Summing the geometric series we get  $f'(x)=\frac x {1+x^{2}}$. So $f(x)=\frac 1  2\ln (1+x^{2})+c$ and $c=0$ because $f(0)=0$.